Viewpoint .XLSX Toolkit: Access To Freeze Top Row In Worksheet
I am using Viewpoint .XLSX Toolkit for Labview. Can I access the Freeze Panes to freeze the top row in a worksheet?
I searched all VI blocks in the toolkit utilities and could not find an option to freeze a row in the spreadsheet.
